# Getting key name in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

In wxWidgets, I'm capturing the `wxKeyDown` event, which gives me a `wxKeyEvent`. I need to get the name of the key that was pressed (e.g. "F1", "Del", "Home", "A") to display to the user, however the closest I have found is `wxKeyEvent::GetUnicodeKey()`:

```
void OnKeyDown(wxKeyEvent &event)
{
    wxMessageBox(wxString::Format("Key pressed: %c", event.GetUnicodeKey()));
}
```

The only other solution I have found is to use a switch statement with keys that do not have a Unicode representation (e.g. Del). Is there any other way to retrieve the name of the key that was pressed?

Comment: Keys just have numbers, not names.  Names are difficult, they have to be localized.  "Home" only ever means something to an English speaker.  The user would expect to see back whatever the paint on the pressed key says.  If you run this code on Windows then you could call GetKeyNameText().  But of course it ports like a stone brick, the only good reason to use wxWidgets is to not do this.

Comment: @HansPassant My application does not have support for different locales. Is there no OS-independent way to get the English name of a key that was pressed?

Comment: *Somebody* has to write the code to make it OS and locale independent.  That somebody is you right now.  Don't forget to submit the patch back to the project so others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in function to get the name of the key, but you can see how to do it for most (and maybe even all the) special keys in the [keyboard sample](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/v3.0.2/samples/keyboard/keyboard.cpp#L346-L485).

EDIT: Actually there is one function I didn't think of: [wxAcceleratorEntry::ToString()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0.2/classwx_accelerator_entry.html#a0d164fa98bba518e6b6f9cca65332d36). It is rather roundabout but you probably could use `wxAcceleratorEntry(0 /* no modifiers */, keycode).ToString()` to return a reasonably user-friendly description of the key.